# Resize root partition using uncontiguous free space

Tags: partitioning

The partition table is looking this way:

```
|NTFS|FREE-SPACE|LINUX-BOOT|LINUX-EXTENDED|
```

I want to resize (make bigger) my LINUX-EXTENDED partition (actually the `/` partition inside it), to take the FREE-SPACE.

1. I noticed with GParted it is not possible just to resize this way. Is it so, that ext4 doesn't allow it?
2. I thought about this solution: extend LINUX-BOOT to the left, and shrink it from the right to the original size. Than the same for the LINUX-BOOT partition, and finally just extend the LINUX-EXTEND partition.

**Question**: After such a resize, will the data on all partitions remain uncorrupt (will such a resize move also the files to the beginning)?

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you describe should work. I have resized my ext4 partitions many times using gparted.

Why do you say "it is not possible"? What happens when you try?

Although gparted is very reliable, you should always backup important data before making any partition changes.